# Displayport to HDMI no audio

Tags: audio, displayport, hdtv

Here's a link to a thread I made on another forum with all the details: http://www.pchelpforum.com/xf/threads/displayport-to-hdmi-no-sound.158412/

I'm having a problem trying to connect my hdtv as a second monitor. The video is fine but the sound comes out through my main monitor as it usually does. My graphics card is a Sapphire 7970 and I have tried re-installing the drivers for it already. I've been having this problem for about a week now and everywhere else I've tried has been no help so I really hope you guys can help me out here. How do I get the sound to go through my TV?

Comment: Can you please use a question mark to denote your question, I'm having trouble finding it on this page

Comment: There is still no question here. You know what you want, but .....

Comment: Rather than add comments, you can edit your question. As it is it will be closed.

Comment: Not a wiz on modern graphics boards, but how does the board access the system sound? Maybe there is a cable inside or a configuration in Catalyst that should be connected/activated.

Comment: Rather than linking to another site, it would be helpful if you could include all relevant details in your question here.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the hardware, it just looks like you haven't changed the audio to come out of the HDTV.  In your audio devices there should be something that represents your HDTV.  You can determine what it is by having it plugged in, watching the audio devices and then unplugging it and seeing which disappears or can't be used.  Once you know what it is, plug the HDTV back in and then in audio devices again, right-click on it and make it 'Default'.  That should hopefully fix it for ya.

Comment: Just tried that and none of the audio devices were removed when I unplugged the TV. I also get a pop-up saying an HDMI-to-DVI connection was detected and that to use sound I need a separate connection. This is probably the problem but I don't understand why it's saying that it's a DVI connection when it's Displayport to HDMI. All of the reviews on amazon also said that the sound worked on this cable so I'm really confused.

Comment: You'll most likely need to change the audio settings in the AMD Catalyst program.

Comment: In catalyst I go to the audio settings tab and I can choose between my desktop monitor and the TV, when I switch over to the TV to change settings it says "Your displays do not support audio. Select another audio device from the list above.